# How to pass the selected data from Select2 Minimal?

Tags: php, codeigniter, autocomplete, jquery-select2

**How can I pass data from the selection, is it via AJAX or direct to controller? Im using Codeigniter for the framework and AdminLTE for the admin theme.**

> Here's my HTML CODE:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
      <?php foreach ($donates as $index => $donate) : ?>
         <option selected="selected" id="m_id" name="m_id">
         <?php echo $donate->m_id; ?>
         </option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be relevant to see how you are initializing the select2 plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set name for the select node instead of option node.
For example

```
<select name="m_id">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
</select>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)